# Need to detect if a url contains a certain folder and if it does strip that folder out

Tags: url, redirect

We recently moved our communities to the cloud and with that we moved all subfolders up one level.

So, previously we had:

www.mywebsite.com/abcd/otherstuff/index.htm

And now our folder structure is:

www.mywebsite.com/otherstuff/index.htm

We've stripped out the abcd from all URLS in the website itself. The problem is, there's lots of tech notes and bookmarks out there in the world that still point to the old URL and they are getting a 404 and a lot of people are not happy.

Is it possible to write a script that enables our communities to detect the presence of abcd in the URL, strip it out, parse the remainder and direct the browser to the correct address?

What language would one write this in? Would it go in the HTTACCESS file? Has anyone done anything similar before?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't done it but you may find this information useful: http://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/redirecting-a-web-folder-directory-to-another-in-htaccess/

Comment: I'm hoping that that will work OK. With it being in the cloud getting access to the httaccess might be the hardest issue.